# Resolving Effects and Maybes

Tags: purescript

```
spec = describe "Router" $ do

  let sampleRoutes = [( Tuple "/"  "views/index.yaml" ), 
                      ( Tuple "/foo" "views/foo.yaml" ), 
                      ( Tuple "/bar" "views/bar.yaml" )]

  it "should default to the first of the list" $ do
    r <- fst <$> head sampleRoutes
    fprint r
```

The above throws the following error:

```
Error in declaration spec
Cannot unify Data.Maybe.Maybe with Control.Monad.Eff.Eff u4505.
```

I believe its because it is expect a second argument that is of type `Eff`, but because of 
the use of `Maybe` introduced by `head` the second arguments ends up being of type `Maybe` instead.

```
it :: forall e a. String -> Eff e a -> Eff (it :: It | e) Unit
```

The problem is, I have no idea how to resolve this. Can I not have a `Maybe` instead an effectful block of code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Maybe` can be used in a `do` block, but all of the actions in the block have to be of type `Maybe a` for some `a`.

The same is true for `Eff eff` - you can use `Eff eff` with `do`, but all actions have to be of type `Eff eff a` for some `a`.

You can't mix and match the two types of effects within a `do` block.

It looks like you want to use a value of type `Maybe a` inside a `do` block whose monad is `Eff eff`. You have a couple of options:

- Use `Data.Array.Unsafe.head` which will give you an unwrapped `Tuple`, which you can call `fst` on directly.
- Pattern match on the `Maybe` value to decide the course of action in the `Eff` monad:

  ```
  it "should default to the first of the list" $ do
    case head sampleRoutes of
      Nothing -> ... -- Handle empty array
      Just tuple -> fprint (fst tuple) -- Print the first component
    .. rest of do block ..
  ```

Comment: I need to check, but I'm not sure this solves it. Can I `return` under the case statement? Doesn't this still make the do block return `Maybe` instead of `Eff`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `return`, but it will be `return` for the `Eff` monad. The return type of the expression I wrote is `Eff eff a`.

Comment: so just `return Unit` under the case statement and the types will resolve?

Comment: That would work, unless there's some other effect you want to have happen in that case.

Comment: So the case statement also works without handling `Nothing`, shouldn't that be a non-exhaustive patterns error?

Comment: Possibly yes, but the compiler doesn't check exhaustivity right now. When it does, yes, this would be a warning/error.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, it's also possible to make use of [`traverse_`](http://www.purescript.org/pursuit/?traverse_) from `Data.Foldable`.

Since you're working with a `Maybe (Tuple String String)`, `Maybe` has a `Foldable` instance, and `Eff e` has an applicative instance, you can use [`traverse_`](http://www.purescript.org/pursuit/?traverse_) rather than `(<$>)`.

You just need to supply a function `Tuple String String -> Eff e a` for some `a`. If you compose `fst` and `fprint`, you get exactly that.

Your example becomes

```
spec = describe "Router" $ do

  let sampleRoutes = [( Tuple "/"  "views/index.yaml" ), 
                      ( Tuple "/foo" "views/foo.yaml" ), 
                      ( Tuple "/bar" "views/bar.yaml" )]

  it "should default to the first of the list" $ 
    traverse_ (fst >>> fprint) $ head sampleRoutes
```